# pass parameters to a javascript function without using an inline function inside jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So after reading a few articles on react native performance, I realized that you're supposed to avoid arrow functions inside JSX.
https://blog.codemagic.io/improve-react-native-app-performance/#avoid-arrow-functions

But I have the following react-native code

```
function Layout() {

    function handlePress(index) {
        console.log("Inside HandlePress", index)
        // I want index here
    }

    function NavItemIterable(item, index) {
        return(
            // how to pass index without arrow functions
            <Pressable key={index} onPress={handlePress}>
                <NavItem />
            </Pressable>
            )
    }

    return(
        <Box>
            {data.map(NavItemIterable)}
        </Box>
        )
}
```

With arrow functions, I could do something like
`<Pressable key={index} onPress={()=> handlePress(index)}>`.

How can I avoid an arrow function is this case & still call `handlePress` with `index`.
(or should I even try to avoid)

Comment: *should I even try to avoid* is the more important question. No, you don't need to try and avoid it. This is a micro-optimization. If you don't need an arrow function, then don't use it. But it's very rare that this would cause an observable performance problem

Comment: Without getting into whether or not arrow-function deserves to stay or go, and only focusing on replacing arrow with function. `<Pressable key={index} onPress={()=> handlePress(index)}>` ---> this is an anonymous arrow function. May be the equivalent is: `<Pressable key={index} onPress={function() {handlePress(index); }}>`

Comment: @jsN00b the performance hit comes in because you are declaring a new function on every render as opposed to say a class component where the function may be a method that is stable across renders. In a function component, all the functions inside are redeclared anyway, so unless you use `useCallback`, inline vs named makes very little if any difference. Arrow vs function keyword will have the exact same tradeoffs.

Comment: The arrow function optimization argument is also only valid if the child component is memoized. If it isn't, Reacts default behavior is to re-render all children when the parent re-renders. So the whole optimization argument is moot in 98% of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That blog post you have mentioned](https://blog.codemagic.io/improve-react-native-app-performance/#avoid-arrow-functions) is at least misleading, and doesn't give sufficient context to understand it's statement (e.g. why you would even use a nested function in that case at all).

Your example (a function component) is fundamentally different to the one in that blog post (a class component).

In your example, **it is ok to use a function** to "pass" the parameters to the handler.
That is generally inline with common react principles, and it doesn't matter a lot if you are using
an arrow function (`const f = () => {};`) or a classic function (`const f = function(){};`). (optimizations are still possible.)

#### What the blog post says, and doesn't say ...

The blog post states that you should *"Avoid Arrow Functions"*, and gives an example.

In that example there *is* a difference between using a classic and an arrow function, but that isn't the actual problem,
and the blog post doesn't say why you would use an extra function there at all (no matter if classic or arrow function) ?

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  addTodo() {}
  render() {
    return <>
      <MyComponent onClick={ () => this.addTodo()         /* <-- Why would you even do this ? ...   */ } />
      <MyComponent onClick={ function(){ this.addTodo() } /* <-- ... even with a classic function ? */ } />
      <MyComponent onClick={ this.addTodo } />            /* <-- Recommended. */
    </>;
  }
}
```

Of course, you should avoid that extra function, if there is no reason to add it.

#### What the blog post probably means ...

A common reason to use an extra function there is to capture the `this` context of the class. Indeed, here you *need* to use an arrow function.

In this example, **only the arrow function will work** *(and the alternative)*, because it captures the `this` context of the component:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  myValue = 'some value';
  addTodo(){
    try { console.log( 'ok, value is:', this.myValue ); }
    catch(_){
      console.error( 'error: `this` is:', this );
    }
  }
  render() {
    const capturedThis = this;
    return <>
      <button onClick={ () => this.addTodo()          } > arrow: works. </button>
      <button onClick={ this.addTodo                  } > no extra function: error. </button>
      <button onClick={ function(){ this.addTodo(); } } > classic function: worse error! </button>
      <button onClick={ function(){ capturedThis.addTodo(); } } > classic alternative: works. </button>
    </>;
  }
}
```

#### What the blog post missed ...

The captured `this` context ("closure") might cause problems. That is probably why the blog post recommends to avoid it.

But the actual recommendation should not be to *"avoid arrow functions"*, but to *avoid capturing the `this` context in a closure* (which is usually done by using an arrow function).

A solution would be to **bind the method to the component**:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this); // <-- bind method to the components `this`
    }
    myValue = 'some value';
    addTodo(){
        console.log( 'ok, value is:', this.myValue );
    }
    render() {
        return <>
            <button onClick={ this.addTodo } > works without arrow function </button>
        </>;
    }
}
```

##### Remark:

I would recommend that you just should forget that you have ever read the misleading recommendation in that blog post, and find better sources of knowledge.

I think closures, the `.bind(this)` pattern and optimizing functional components are beyond the scope of this question topic.

If you still want to optimize your functional component, unrelated to that blog post, then I think you should ask a new question.